# Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{A}\sin(nx)dx = 0$ for any Lebesgue measurable $A \subseteq [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I have to show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{A}\sin(nx)dx = 0$$

for any Lebesgue Measurable $A \subseteq [0,1]$

I have seen many solutions which invoke several theorems from real analysis that I do not study on my course (Riemann-Lebesgue lemma for example). I want to see different approaches to understand better the problem and try to solve this with my methods. I covered the Royden book up to chapter 5.

Comment: The inequality $\int_A \sin nx\,dx\le \int_0^1 \sin nx\,dx$ is incorrect, as $\sin nx$ is sometimes negative.

Comment: How do you know that $\sin(nx)$ is non-negative for $x\in[0,1]\setminus A$?

Comment: Did you know a simpler approach ? Thank you. I didn't catch that.

Comment: Show the result holds for intervals, and then use the fact that any lebesgue measurable set can be approximated from above as countable unions of intervals.

Comment: this is an immediate consequence of the Bessel inequality applied to $\chi_{A}$, the characteristic function of $A$

Comment: You can use the technique I used in this blog post of mine https://www.math.tolaso.com.gr/?p=1195 and adjust it a bit !!

Comment: Of course you may read about Riemann - Lebsegue Lemma!

Comment: Right, the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma is probably the easiest path here. $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_A \sin(nx)\,\mathrm{d}x = \lim_{n\to \infty} \Im\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 1_Ae^{inx}\,\mathrm{d}x\right] = 0$$

Comment: No `\displaystyle` in titles please. // "I have seen many solutions which invoke several theorems from real analysis. I want to see different approaches" How can we answer this if we do not know the "many solutions" you already know?

Comment: @Did, I posted previously a partial solution and ask for a different one and a proof check. Anyway, I did not use "displaystyle" in the title. I know is not allowed here.

Comment: @Did by the way, I modified the question.

Comment: Displaystyle in titles: oh right, I now see this unfortunate edit was suggested by user BenjaminMoss and accepted by users MyGlasses and
user3658307, who should all know better. Apologies.

Comment: The revised version of the question is more precise.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $A$ measurable, $\mu(A) < \infty$.  Then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $B$ a finite union of intervals such that 
$$\mu(A \Delta B) < \epsilon$$
Indeed, first take $K$ compact so that $\mu(A\Delta K) < \epsilon/2$, then $U$ open, $U\supset K$, so that $\mu(K\Delta U) < \epsilon/2$. Now $U$ is a union of intervals, and finitely many of them will cover $K$, so take $B$ that finite cover.

Now one can reduce the problem  to the case $A$ a  finite interval, which is simple.

$\bf{Added:}$ One can show in this way that $\int_A \sin(\lambda x) dx \to 0$ as $\lambda \to \infty$.

Comment: Is not easier to consider the open set $O$ such that $A \subset O$ and $m(O\setminus A) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and then $$ \int_{A}\sin(nx)dx = \int_{O}\sin(nx)dx - \int_{O\setminus A}\sin(nx)dx$$ then $$ |\int_{A}\sin(nx)dx| \leq  |\int_{O}\sin(nx)dx| + |\int_{O\setminus A}\sin(nx)dx| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + |\int_{O}\sin(nx)dx| $$ then reduce this to an open set case of countable open sets which is easy ?

Comment: @Richard Clare: It is easy for a finite union of intervals, to which you have to reduce. In whatever way you prefer I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof avoiding analysis (basically reproving [Bessel's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_inequality) as mentioned by user363464). I will use these facts:

1. There is an inner product
   $$\langle f,g\rangle=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f g$$
   defined on $L_2([0,2 \pi])$.
2. The functions $s_n$ defined by $s_n(x)=\sin nx$ for $n\geq 1$ are orthonormal: $$\langle s_n, s_m\rangle=\begin{cases}
   0\text{ if }n\neq m\\
   1\text{ if }n=m
   \end{cases}$$

(Actually I won't use that $\langle.,.\rangle$ is positive definite, and it only has to operate on a vector space including $\chi_A$ and the functions $s_n$.)

Define $a_n=\langle \chi_A, s_n\rangle$. We need to show $|a_n|\to 0$.

For each $N$ we can define $g_N=\chi_A-\sum_{n=1}^Na_ns_n$. Then
$$\chi_A=a_1s_1+\dots+a_Ns_N + g_N$$
but these terms are all orthogonal, so
$$\langle\chi_A,\chi_A\rangle=\langle a_1s_1,a_1s_1\rangle+\dots+\langle a_Ns_N, a_Ns_N\rangle + \langle g_N,g_N\rangle$$
Using $\langle g_N,g_N\rangle\geq 0$ and $\langle s_n,s_n\rangle=1$ we get
$$\langle\chi_A,\chi_A\rangle\geq a_1^2+\dots+a_N^2$$
so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2$ converges, which implies $a_n\to 0$.

Comment: You are using that $\{\sin(nx)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an orthogonal family of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ which contains $1_{x \in A}$. Not sure why you need to write the rest.

Comment: Neat solution ! Your method shows that $\sum_{n\ge 1} a_{\frac{n}{l}}^2 < \pi l \mu(A)$ for any $l >0$. It would imply $a_{n d} \to 0 $ , $n \to \infty$ for all $d > 0$. But  this would imply then $a_y \to 0$ as $y \to \infty$.